# Plot a plm model in R

Tags: r, plm

I have a large panel which I am estimating via plm with fixed effects.

For example

```
Test.fe <- plm( Y ~ x1+x2, data=test, model="within")
```

I used `summary(Test.fe)` to print the estimating results  and to get the fixed effects, it is possible to use `fixef`.

But now my question: **How can I plot the estimated Y values to compare with my real Y values?**

Thanks.

Comment: Potential [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123060/is-there-a-predict-function-for-plm-in-r) (asking about fitted values from `plm`).

Comment: You could avoid having this be a duplicate by extracting a portion of your data and posting using dput() to create a working example. I will remove my vote to close if you do that.

Comment: A simple way to get the fitted values 

     fitted.panelmodel <- plm(object, ...)
     object$model[[1]] - object$residuals

There is currently no better method for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to get the fitted values

```
 fitted.panelmodel <- plm(object, ...)
 object$model[[1]] - object$residuals
```

There is currently no better method for that.

Comment: Add this to your question, not as an answer.

Comment: I think this answer is too terse to be really useful: object will not contain 'object$residuals' unless they are assigned from 'fitted.panelmodel'