# Prediction with plm method

Tags: r, predict, panel-data, plm

I'm using plm package to estimate a random effects model on panel data.
Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209689/plm-using-fixef-to-manually-calculate-fitted-values-for-a-fixed-effects-twowa) about the prediction in plm package gives me some doubts. How exactly it works? I tried 3 alternatives methods and they give different solutions. Why ?

```
library(data.table); library(plm)

set.seed(100)
DT <- data.table(CJ(id=c(1,2,3,4), time=c(1:10)))
DT[, x1:=rnorm(40)]
DT[, x2:=rnorm(40)]
DT[, y:=x1 + 2*x2 + rnorm(40)/10 + id]
DT <- DT[!(id=="a" & time==4)] # just to make it an unbalanced panel
setkey(DT, id, time)    

summary(plmFEit <- plm(data=DT, id=c("id","time"), formula=y ~ x1 + x2, model="random"))    
    ###################
    #method 1
    ###################
    # Extract the fitted values from the plm object
    FV <- data.table(plmFEit$model, residuals=as.numeric(plmFEit$residuals))
    FV[, y := as.numeric(y)]
    FV[, x1 := as.numeric(x1)]
    FV[, x2 := as.numeric(x2)]

    DT <- merge(x=DT, y=FV, by=c("y","x1","x2"), all=TRUE)
    DT[, fitted.plm_1 := as.numeric(y) - as.numeric(residuals)]                
    ###################
    #method 2
    ###################        
    # calculate the fitted values 
    DT[, fitted.plm_2 := as.numeric(coef(plmFEit)[1]+coef(plmFEit)[2] * x1 + coef(plmFEit)[3]*x2)]                
    ###################
    #method 3
    ###################
    # using pmodel.response 
    DT$fitted.plm_3 <-pmodel.response(plmFEit,model='random')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**
This can be done easier:

```
FV <- data.table(plmFEit$model, residuals=as.numeric(plmFEit$residuals))
FV[ , fitted := y - residuals]
```

However, it gives the same fitted values like in you approach with `merge()`

**Method 2:**
You are fitting a random effects model (albeit you name it plmFEit, where FE usually implies fixed effects). Compared to method 1, you are missing the idiosyncratic error term.

**Method 3:**
`pmodel.response()` gives you the response variable (in this case that would be `y`) but with the specified transformation (random effects transformation ("quasi demeaning")) applied to it (see `pmodel.response()`).

I think, what you want is given by method 1.