# Predicting with plm function in R

Tags: r, predict, pooling, plm

I was wondering if it is possible to predict with the plm function from the plm package in R for a new dataset of predicting variables. I have create a model object using:

```
model <- plm(formula, data, index, model = 'pooling')
```

Now I'm hoping to predict a dependent variable from a new dataset which has not been used in the estimation of the model. I can do it through using the coefficients from the model object like this:

```
col_idx <- c(...)
df <- cbind(rep(1, nrow(df)), df[(1:ncol(df))[-col_idx]])
fitted_values <- as.matrix(df) %*% as.matrix(model_object$coefficients)
```

Such that I first define index columns used in the model and dropped columns due to collinearity in col_idx and subsequently construct a matrix of data which needs to be multiplied by the coefficients from the model. However, I can see errors occuring much easier with the manual dropping of columns.

A function designed to do this would make the code a lot more readable I guess. I have also found the pmodel.response() function but I can only get this to work for the dataset which has been used in predicting the actual model object.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you need help with? It seems like a statistical question rather than a coding one... What do you mean with " I can see errors occuring much easier with the manual dropping of columns."?

Comment: See the `?pmodel.response`

Comment: I checked `?pmodel.responde` but for the class of my model output object, which is 'plm' and 'panelmodel', using a dataframe containing predictive features as an argument for the parameter 'data' returns the original predictive values for the dataset on which the model is trained.

Comment: If you want to predict from a pooled model, just go with estimating your model by `lm()` and then use `predict.lm()` with argument `newdata`.

Comment: I think this should answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904457/4640346

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function (`predict.out.plm`) to do out of sample predictions after estimating First Differences or Fixed Effects models with `plm`.

The function is posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185441/2409896